# How to use dynamic FontAwesome icons in NextJs SSR?

Tags: next.js, font-awesome

I want to dynamically render FontAwesome icons within a NextJs project where a page is being rendered using SSR. I don't know which icons will be rendered until runtime, so I am wanting to render the icons by referring to them by using a string: I cannot import just them individually by name at build time.

```
// within my component

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

export function MyComponent({icon}) {
    return (
        ...
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon}/>
        ...
    );
}
```

In my page, I am trying this:

```
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(fas);

.. within my page JSX:
MyComponent<icon={'fa-solid fa-cube'}/>
```

When I run NextJs in development mode, I see in the server logs errors that look like:

```
Could not find icon { prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'cube' }
```

and I also get a browser error "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

However, when I run a production build and serve that, the page renders ok.

How do I import all of the FontAwesome icons in NextJs and serve them dynamically using SSR?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/19348) discussing precisely this problem.

A temporary workaround is to `require()` the `library` instance instead of `import`ing it ([reference](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/19348#issuecomment-1262137893)).